# How do I migrate my Transmission state & settings to another user account?

Tags: linux, bittorrent, migration, transmission

Suppose I want to migrate my transmission configuration settings and current "state" (which torrents are active, which are paused, etc.) - from one user account to another, either on the same machine or another machine.

What actions do I need to take?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you need to:

- Make sure the new user has write and execute access to the "Save to" and "Incomplete" torrent directories the old user was working with, or move the old user directories to someplace accessible to the new one
- Copy the the old user's `$HOME/.config/transmission` directory to the same location for the new user.
- Finally (i.e. after replicating the configuration), and using either the UI or editing `$HOME/.config/transmission/settings.json` update the directories for the new user according to whether you've moved the old directories or made them accessible otherwise. (The relevant settings are `"download-dir"` and `"incomplete-dir"`.)

**Note:** If the new user *already has* a Tranmission profile, you'll be overwriting your `settings.json` and `dht.dat` file, but you should merge your `stats.json` values (manually is fine, it's just a few numbers). The rest of it will be automatically "merged" since those are separate `.torrent` and `.resume` files in two subdirectories (and perhaps blocklist data, although that's usually empty).

Answer (score 0):

FYI, if you want to migrate torrents, you can use my script https://github.com/machsix/transmission-migrate

Answer (score 0):

This method is a far less sophisticated and takes longer:

1. Take out and place your old Mac Drive into an **external 2.5 HDD enclosure**
2. Attach the enclosure to the USB port of your new Mac
3. On the new mac type **Migration Assistant** in the spotlight search bar and the app will find your external drive
4. Select the external drive (orange coloured) and it will find transfer your applications, files, and everything!
5. You can include/omit 3 categories before migrating: **files, apps, and network settings**

When I opened Transmission 3.0 (yes all apps were migrated as well) all my torrent colour tags/labels and torrents were preserved. The file integrity check was skipped, saving my hdd from checking everything all over again.

Notes:

- Some apps on an older version of MacOS will not work once migrated to
  newer versions of MacOS. Download updates for them.
- Pirated apps may not work depending on how they were cracked.
- If you don't have an external hard drive enclosure, manually copy everything off your old Mac hard drive onto a usb key or external drive and it will work as well, but try to get the whole thing to fit into 1 drive. No partial transfers.

Comment: This question was about Linux, not MacOS.